# How to append HTML content using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

All what I want to do is, when the user clicks on a button, the content of the `div` should append at the bottom. My code works fine if I paste the content inside the `div` in the javascript displayed below:

My question:

1.) Without having to copy paste the code that was in the `HTML` to `JAVASCRIPT` is there any other way I could get this done.

2.) I want the `name` and also the `value` attribute of the input field to be unique (like append a number at the end ). How can I do this ?

My `jQuery` looks like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){


      $("#btn").click(function(){
          $("#boxid").append('<br/>
<div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myid" placeholder="hey" value="2">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">?</div>
                  </div>
            ');
      });

  });
```

HTML

```
<button id="btn">Add another row</button>
 <form action="gone/" method="get">
<div id="boxid">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myid" placeholder="hey" value="2">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">?</div>
                  </div>

</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You cannot have multi-line strings in JavaScript (well you can, but you need to escape the new line characters). Put all the HTML inside the `append()` method call in a single line.

Comment: You could also look at stuff like `document.createElement(xxx)`, to create your elements rather than using the string.

Comment: Also new lines can be escaped by `\\`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/).

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var counter = $('.form-control').last().val();//Get the last .form-control value, in case you decide to have more than one by default (this way the counter can start from 2 e.g)
     $("#btn").click(function() {
         counter++; //Increase counter
         $("#boxid").append($('.input-group').eq(0).clone()); //Clone the existing first .input-group
         $("#boxid .input-group").last().find('.form-control').attr('name', counter).val(counter); //Select the last appended .input-group, find the .form-control input, change input's name and value with the counter
     });
 });
```

```css
.input-group{
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Add another row</button>
<form action="gone/" method="get">
    <div id="boxid">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myid" placeholder="hey" value="1" name="1">
            <div class="input-group-addon">?</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

- Initialize counter with the last input's value
- In case of click on `#btn` increase counter.
- Append to `#boxid` the clone of the first (.eq(0)) `.input-group` (It doesn't really matter if it's the first, just used it as first = template).
- Select the last `.input-group` inside `#boxid` and change its `name` and value with the counter.
- I left your `<br>`behind, is not used nowadays, a more correct way is using css margin (a margin of `1em` is like 1 text line)

Answer (score 0):

When i need something like this is, i use a hidden `div` containing template elements. When ever i need a realization of a template, i simply copy the template, change some placeholders and add it to my target element.

PS: include https://jsfiddle.net/cvf2f7dn/1/ of @Illep

css

```
#templates { display: none }
```

html

```
<div id="targetDiv"></div>
<div id="templates">
  <div id="templeateForInputGroup">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myid%%counter%%" placeholder="hey" value="%%counter%%">
      <div class="input-group-addon">?</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="addmore">Add more</button>
```

js

```
$('#addmore').click(add);

String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
  var target = this;
  return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};

var counter = 0;
function add(){
  var cloneHTML = $('#templeateForInputGroup').html().toString();
  cloneHTML = cloneHTML.replaceAll('%%counter%%', counter);
  counter++;
  $('#targetDiv').append(cloneHTML);
}
```

Comment: how can I click on a button to add another row (with the content of the div)

Comment: @Illep To assist this answer (which is the correct one), I made a fiddle to show how to use the answer, as you are clearly still in doubt https://jsfiddle.net/cvf2f7dn/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){


      $("#btn").click(function(){

if(checkUnique('myid')){//to check unique id
          $("#boxid").append('<br/>
<div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myid" placeholder="hey" value="2">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">?</div>
                  </div>
            ');
}

else{
$("#boxid").append('<br/>
<div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myid1" placeholder="hey" value="2">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">?</div>
                  </div>
            ');
}
      });

  });

function checkUnique(ex){
if($('#'+ex).length==0){
return true;}
else
{return false;}
}
```